# How to fix incorrect top offset in internet explore

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, offset

I am trying to dynamically set a div height the remainder of the screen below my header. The code I have works in chrome etc. but in IE the offset().top values are incorrect and the height does not equal the remainder of the screen. I set a header placeholder div just after my header and then a footer placeholder with absolute position at bottom of page. when inspecting elements, the two placeholder divs are in the correct place, but the height calculation is wrong.

Please help.

I have tried using the jquery offset().top and the normal javascript offsetTop. Both work fine in other browsers, but not in IE

```
alert($('#ftr-plcHldr').offset().top);
alert($('#hdr-end').offset().top);
alert(calcedHeight);

//IN CHROME WHICH IS CORRECT:
968 //Footer place holder offset
96 //Header place holder offset
872 //Calculated Height

//IN IE WHICH IS INCORRECT:
961 //Footer place holder offset
193.28 //Header place holder offset
767.2 //Calculated Height



var calcedHeight = $('#ftr-plcHldr').offset().top - $('#hdr-end').offset().top;


Html:
<div style="background:#3f3f3f;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12" style="text-align:right;padding:5px;">
                <div style="float:left;padding-top: 8px; padding-bottom: 7px; padding-left: 10px;cursor:pointer;">
                    <a style="color:chocolate;"><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i> My Config</a>
                </div>
                <div style="float:right;border-left-color: black; border-left-width: 1px; border-left-style: solid;margin-left: 25px;padding-left:10px;">
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" style="border: 1px solid grey; border-image: none; color: white; background-color: transparent;width:100px;">
                            Menu
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                            <li>
                                <a style="cursor:pointer;">Approval Inbox</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a style="cursor:pointer;">Dashboard</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="padding-top: 8px; padding-bottom: 7px; padding-left: 10px; float: right;cursor:pointer;">
                    <a style="color:darkgoldenrod;"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Shopping Basket</a>
                </div>
                <div style="clear:right;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="hdr-end" style="width:100%;height:1px;"></div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="content-holder" class="col-xs-12" style="overflow-y:auto;position:relative;">
CONTENT THAT FILL THE REST OF THE SCREEN
</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="ftr-plcHldr" style="position:absolute;bottom:0;width:100%;height:1px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to find the problem/solution.

The issue is caused by an image where the width was set in the css.

The image was originally 160px and the css sets the width to 134px.

Changing the actual width on the image to 134px has resolved the issue.

I am still not sure why though, since this was not a problem in other browsers, but it has resolved this issue.